# If $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers, then the cube of the largest cannot be equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

Prove, by contradiction, that, if $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers, then the cube of the largest cannot be equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

---

**Proposition:** If $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers, then the cube of the largest cannot be equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

**Hypothesis:** $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers.

**Conclusion:** The cube of the largest cannot be equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

---

**My workings**

**A (Hypothesis):** $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers.

**A1 ($\neg B$):** The cube of the largest *is* equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

**A2:** There exists $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ such that $(n + 1)^3 = (n - 1)^3 + n^3$.

**A3:** $(n+1)^3 = (n - 1)^3 + n^3 $

$\implies (n + 1)(n^2 + 2n + 1) = (n-1)(n^2 - 2n + 1) + n^3$

$\implies n^3 + 2n^2 + n + n^2 + 2n + 1 = n^3 - 2n^2 + n - n^2 + 2n - 1 + n^3$

$\implies n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 = 2n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1$

$\implies n^3 - 6n^2 - 2 = 0$

**A4:** $n^3 - 6n^2 - 2 = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$.

$\implies 1 - \dfrac{6}{n} - \dfrac{2}{n^3} = 0$

$\implies 1 - \dfrac{6}{n} = \dfrac{2}{n^3}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$.

But there is no $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ such that $1 - \dfrac{6}{n} = \dfrac{2}{n^3}$. ***Contradiction.***

$Q.E.D.$

---

**EDIT: My workings #2**

**A (Hypothesis):** $n − 1$, $n$, and $n + 1$ are consecutive positive integers.

**A1 ($\neg B$):** The cube of the largest *is* equal to the sum of the cubes of the other two.

**A2:** There exists $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ such that $(n + 1)^3 = (n - 1)^3 + n^3$.

**A3:** $(n+1)^3 = (n - 1)^3 + n^3 $

$\implies (n + 1)(n^2 + 2n + 1) = (n-1)(n^2 - 2n + 1) + n^3$

$\implies n^3 + 2n^2 + n + n^2 + 2n + 1 = n^3 - 2n^2 + n - n^2 + 2n - 1 + n^3$

$\implies n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 = 2n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1$

$\implies n^3 - 6n^2 - 2 = 0$

**A4:** $n^3 - 6n^2 - 2 = 0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$.

$\implies n^2(n - 6) - 2 = 0$

$\implies n^2(n - 6) = 2$

**A5:** $n^2(n - 6) = 2$

$n^2(n - 6) \le 0$ when $6 \ge n > 1$.

$n^2(n - 6) \ge 0$ when $n > 6$

$\therefore$ When $6 \ge n > 1$, $n^2(n - 6) \not = 2$.

**A6:** $n^2(n - 6) = 2 > 0$

$n^2(n - 6) > 0$

$\implies n - 6 > 0$

$\implies n > 6$

$\therefore \inf(n - 6) = 1$ where $n = 7 > 6$

But $\inf(n^2) = 7^2$ where $n = 7 > 6$

$= 49$

The function $f(n) = n^2(n - 6)$ is continuous, positive, and increasing on the interval $[7, \infty)$.

$\therefore \inf[n^2(n - 6)] = 49(1)$

$= 49 \not = 2$ ***Contradiction.***

$Q.E.D.$

---

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof and provide feedback on its correctness.

Comment: How can you conclude that there is no such n in the last line of your proof? It is not rigorous.

Comment: Well I didn't quite get your idea but you could try showing that the last equation has no integral roots.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Ok, I edited with a new solution. I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *last Fermat theorem*.

Set $a=n-1,$ $b=n$ and $c=n+1$. Then you want to prove that: $$a^3+b^3=c^3.$$

We know that this equation has only the trivial solution. So $a=b=c=0$, but this imply that $n$ is equal to $-1$, $0$ and $1$ at the same time which is clearly impossible.

Comment: That's an extremely elegant solution. What do you think of my second solution (the edited solution)?

Comment: It is essentially correct. Maybe it is better to say that: the function $f(x)=x^2(x-6)-2$ is continuous and it is positive and increasing on the interval $[7,+\infty[$ and then infimum is taken at $7$ which is $49$. Since the function is increasing on that interval there are no positive integer such that $n^2(n-6)=2.$

Comment: Perhaps one could note that proving that $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has only the trivial solutions is vastly easier than the general case.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Shall I add it as an edit in the OP?

Comment: @ThePointer, I don't think it is necessary, but the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *need* to show that there is no integer $n>1$ such that
$$
1-\frac{6}{n}=\frac{2}{n^3}
$$
For instance, if $n>6$, then both sides are positive and less than $1$, so they *could* be equal.

However, for $n\ge7$, we have
$$
1-\frac{6}{n}\ge1-\frac{6}{7}=\frac{1}{7}
$$
whereas
$$
\frac{2}{n^3}\le\frac{2}{7^3}<\frac{1}{7}
$$
For $1\le n\le 6$, the left hand side is $\le0$.

Alternatively, the only rational roots of $n^3-6n-2$ can be $\pm1$ and $\pm2$; none of them is a root.

Comment: Simpler: if $n^3=6n^2+2$ then $n^3>6n^2$ hence $n>6$, but then $n^2>2$ hence $n^3=6n^2+2<7n^2$ hence $n<7$. Now, $6<n<7$ has no integer solution.

Comment: @Did thanks for the feedback (both of you). I have edited the OP with a new new proof and would greatly appreciate feedback if possible.